# What are these folders for?

Tags: windows-7, memory-management, user-folders

I have dozens of folders like this in my C:\ drive, I'm not sure what exactly they do (I think they may be related to Windows 7 updates) and I'm running very low on space so i'd like to be able to figure out if I can get rid of them or not.

I'm using Windows 7,

thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say these are temp folders. Have you changed the location of your TEMP folder in the past and accidentally set it to C:\?

Anyway, I would create a new folder on your C drive and move all the folders there. Windows will give an error if folders are in use and then you can't move those. After the move is finished, restart your computer. If your computer starts okay without any error, it is likely that these are left-overs of installations.

If windows starts up with errors, move the files back to your C:\ drive and restart again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I moved them to a folder and restarted my computer with out any issue. But now when I try to delete those folders I need permission from the SYSTEM, I try gaining permission through the security tab but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: I think is the backup is missing of your answer.
That's very important for a user if he/she not know what is the Ubuntu live cd, becouse he can't save out her data, if some value need to for the Windows boot.